# Trouble mapping to DTOs with LINQ

Tags: linq, dto

i've been working with DTOs lately and am unable to determine the issue that this code is having.

I'm mapping Genre names and Movie names to a GenreMovieDto. Visual Studio doesn't show any errors (red lines etc) but when the code is run I get the following:

- $exception  {"The specified type member 'Movies' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."} System.NotSupportedException

My code is the following:

```
    public class Genre
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }

    public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string AgeRating { get; set; }
        public int NumberInStock { get; set; }

        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    }

    public class GenreMovieDto
    {      
        public string GenreName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
```

And my API call:

```
        public IEnumerable<GenreMovieDto> GetGenresWithMovies()
        {
            var genresWithMovies = _context.Genres
                .Include(m => m.Movies)
                .Select(x => new GenreMovieDto
                {
                    GenreName = x.Name,
                    Movies = x.Movies    <<<<< CRASHES HERE
                })
                .ToList();

            return genresWithMovies;
        }
```

Any thoughts ? Any and all suggestions / criticism is welcome :P I'm here to learn.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this (EF doesn't support IEnumerable<...> type member):

```
public class Genre
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So IEnumerable was the problem ? Any idea why ? Thanks for the help by the way. Really appreciated

Comment: @Gilmo, yes IEnumerable is the problem. You csan try that setting back to IEnumerable and then simply trying _context.Genres.Include(m => m.Movies).ToList();